# Generate webapp2 code from swagger

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, swagger, webapp2

I'm developing with webapp2 on GAE.
I want to generate webapp2 server code from swagger code.
But Swagger-Editor does not have generate webapp2 code.

Is there any way to generate webapp2 code from swagger code?

Answer (score 0):

If Swagger doesn't have a support for `webapp2` - someone needs to add it first so you would likely need to implement the generation yourself. See [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/How-to-add-a-generator-for-a-new-language-or-framework) and [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Building-your-own-Templates) for starters.